# JpaRepository returning child for the first item in the list and then only the id for the rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following `Post` class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIdentityInfo(      generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
                        property  = "id", 
                        scope     = Long.class)
public class Post {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String title;
    
    private String subtitle;
    
    private String content;
    
    private String img_url;
    
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp created_on;
    
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp last_updated_on;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable=false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private User creator;
    
}
```

And the following repository that extends JpaRepository

```java
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

    Optional<Post> findById(Long id);
    
    List<Post> findAll();
    
}
```

When returning the result of `findAll()` inside the following controller, only the first creator item is sent completely and the rest just contain the id:

```java
@GetMapping("/news")
    public List<Post> getNews() {
        return postRepository.findAll();
    }
```

This is the JSON I get as result:

```json
[
{"id":15,"title":"Title example #1","subtitle":"Subtitle example #1","content":"Lorem #1 ipsum dolor sit amet","img_url":null,"created_on":"2021-12-01T00:00:00.000+00:00","last_updated_on":"2021-12-01T00:00:00.000+00:00","creator":{"id":1,"username":"user-example","email":"blablabla@gmail.com","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_USER"}]}}

,{"id":25,"title":"Title example #2","subtitle":"Subtitle example #2","content":"Lorem #2 ipsum dolor sit amet","img_url":null,"created_on":"2021-12-01T00:00:00.000+00:00","last_updated_on":"2021-12-01T00:00:00.000+00:00","creator":1}
]
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way I can get the whole child object for every element in the JSON array?

Thanks

EDIT: added the `User` class

```java
@Entity
@Table( name = "users", 
        uniqueConstraints = { 
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email") 
        })
@DiscriminatorValue(value="USER")
public class User extends OwnerEntity {

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp created_on;
    
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp last_updated_on;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_roles", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Institution> institutions;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="creator", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected Set<Post> posts;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Institution> following;
}
```

EDIT 2: Added the OwnerEntity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entities")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIdentityInfo(      generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
                        property  = "id", 
                        scope     = Long.class)
public class OwnerEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;
    
}
```

Comment: Can you add `User` class to your question, please?

Comment: Edited and added, there it is! Thans

Comment: Can you also add `OwnerEntity`? Thanks!

Comment: OwnerEntity.java added!

Comment: Exactly what I thought. Please check my answer below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OwnerEntity` also has `@JsonIdentityInfo`. In its [reference documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) we can read the following:

> Annotation used for indicating that values of annotated type or
> property should be serializing so that instances either contain
> additional object identifier (in addition actual object properties),
> or as a reference that consists of an object id that refers to a full
> serialization. In practice this is done by serializing the first
> instance as full object and object identity, and other references to
> the object as reference values.

This perfectly explains why you are getting the JSON like that. If you don't want this, just remove `@JsonIdentityInfo` but it might be there to fix an infinite recursion while serializing bidirectional relationships (you can read more about this in the following online resource https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion).

Comment: Ok, so I tried that and it worked like a charm. I'm gonna have to solve the infinite recursion on other entities later, maybe I'll include a rework on said part of the solution. Thanks a lot, I'm gonna mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad I could help you ;)